# Get a list of month last days between 2 dates?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, date-range

As the title states, I am trying to get the list of month last days between 2 dates.

**Example:**

- Date 1 -> `2014-08-15`
- Date 2 -> `2014-10-15`

**Expected output**

```
2014-08-31
2014-09-30
```

**The query I am using to achieve this is the following:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT LAST_DAY(TO_DATE('2014-08-15') - 1 + ROWNUM)
FROM ALL_OBJECTS
WHERE TO_DATE('2014-08-15') - 1 + ROWNUM <= TO_DATE('2014-10-15');
```

However I have a feeling there might be a more elegant way to achieve it.

Any input would be appreciated!

Comment: But 2014-10-31 is later than your last date 2014-10-15?

Comment: Indeed it isn't. Fixed and thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the same result as yours:

```sql
select add_months(LAST_DAY(date'2014-08-15'),level-1)
from dual 
connect by add_months(trunc(date'2014-08-15','mm'),level-1)<= date'2014-10-15';
```

But I think 2014-10-31 doesn't satisfy your condition - "between 2 dates".

So probably it should be something like

```sql
select add_months(LAST_DAY(date'2014-08-15'),level-1)
from dual 
connect by add_months(LAST_DAY(date'2014-08-15'),level-1)<=date'2014-10-15';
```

or

```sql
select add_months(LAST_DAY(date'2014-08-15'),level-1)
from dual 
connect by level<=months_between(date'2014-10-15',date'2014-08-15');
```

Final query:

```sql
select add_months(LAST_DAY(date'2014-11-07'),level-1)
from dual where add_months(LAST_DAY(date'2014-11-07'),level-1)<=date'2014-12-07'
connect by add_months(LAST_DAY(date'2014-11-07'),level-1)<=date'2014-12-07';
```

Comment: There's one case where it doesn't work, however - if the range is the same date, f.ex:
'2014-11-07' to '2014-11-07' the output is: '30.11.2014' which is wrong... Any ideas?

Comment: ah, I see. Use this query: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=65274de0dde6a31a96b72ac5d98b78bf